bash eval=False causese execution halted in Rmd
I'm trying to produce an Rmd file within which some code chunks are evaluated while the others are not. All the code chunks are bash and I put eval=False in chunk-labels. But when I knitted the file, error message said "Error: ! object 'False' not found" and the execution halted. Could someone help me out with this?
Below is the chunks I used to test.
```{bash, eval = True}
echo "Do echo me"
```

```{bash, eval = False}
echo "Do not echo me"
```

When I knitted it, it gave the error message:


Try echo = FALSE with right boolean syntax

Just tried it. But it says "object 'True' not found."

@XuHe You are misspelling the constants TRUE and FALSE.

To add on, (just in case in wasn't clear), TRUE and FALSE are to be spelt entirely in uppercase.
